# Using Microsoft template ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity code in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have an asp.net MVC 5 app.

I want a simple solution for Identity - is it advisable to take the Identity template code (ie new project, templates: MVC + Individual User Accounts) - and put that into production?

It only needs email/username & password login - and possibly facebook login later.

I may remap table names - like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I like the idea of not creating a lot of work reconfiguring everything (convention over configuration etc) - and am happy to go with how the template does things.

I am using Dapper.net for data access though I'm happy to stick with EF just for the Identity parts.

What would need to be changed to make this secure & production ready?

I may want to update to newer versions of Identity in future, so the more boilerplate I can keep this the better.

Comment: It is secure and production ready. For using Dapper you may want to look up NuGets that provides I*Storage via Dapper and ditch EF.

Comment: Though you may want to review if you would like everyone to register or only just give admins ability to create new users.

Comment: Ive found a few things - any specific NuGet recommendations?

Comment: Also I suppose I should remove / disable code first if I do stick with EF. Obviously I am not using Code First with Dapper...

Comment: and yes I want admin & user roles (everyone can register but admins will have a separate area to do admin tasks).

Comment: Re nuget recommendations - I've not used any of them, so can't comment on code quality. I suggest find their github repo and pick one with most users involved.

Comment: Yeah they seem to have various flaws - I think I'll stick with EF, less work too & closer to boilerplate...

Comment: Good choice for "less work" - I like it!

Comment: are you joking - ie that it will be more work? I can't tell...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I'm being serious. I don't see much point in replacing default MS solution, by third party library of unknown quality. And as you say - you'll save yourself a lot of headaches in the longer run.

Comment: And as you say - nothing stops you using EF for Identity and Dapper for the rest of your solution. Perfectly good and viable solution.

Comment: ok great - yeah that's my thinking....